# Is there an SE for Cell-phones?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Where would I ask a question pertaining to an ordinary phone? Or just cell phones in general? I saw Windows Phone while browsing the SE database, nothing else really popped out at me. Google didn't bring up anything either. Is that just too small a community to cover with SE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cell phones in general? No. And probably never. Many of the devices you can get on the market already have well-received homes around the network, and combining them all together at this point isn't a great idea. The communities probably wouldn't mesh together well either. Every mobile operating system is quite different, and some apps don't even function the same way across the different platforms.

But there are places to go:

- [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com) for your Android phone related problems.
- [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) for your iPhone related problems.
- [Windows Phone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/) for your, well, Windows Phone related problems.
- Blackberry doesn't have a site because there's not a strong community backing its creation. It's attempted to go through the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) process at least eight times and never gained more than 16 followers in all those attempts.

As always, read through the help center for the appropriate site before asking to make sure your question is accepted.

Comment: What about Super User?

Comment: @dorukayhan Cell phones are explicitly off-topic on Super User.

Comment: @animuson It was looking that way. Thanks!